# use my inputs like input

Tags: sound

HI I'm new in Ubuntu but i had a problem I have one audio output and two audio inputs on my computer. But, I have one microphone, stereo reproductors and headphones. In windows Realtek driver, I could simple change the audio input to output, now I'm using Ubuntu. Is there any option to change the input to output and conversely? Thanks

Comment: Can please edit your question and add the ouput of `lspci | grep -i audio` and the output of `lsusb`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I change the output between a audio jack device and a USB device using the "Audio" Program in Ubuntu. It's the same as clicking on the top right audio icon and choosing th last option (audio settings). There is an input tab, which lists my devices and I can easily change the active one.

Since I'm not sure about your setup, but this may help you or someone with a similar problem. It definitely works for me with a usb device which acts as an own sound card.